# Make particles clump together and flow in a specific direction

Tags: particles

I am creating a cel shaded fire using a particle system in which I want the particles to clump together and flow in a specific direction. Is it possible to make it 'look' and behave more fire-like?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Final better]

This is campfire example.

To achieve this effect add two force fields.

**First one:** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Force Field* > *Turbulence*

Then change *Noise* to 5.

[image: Turbulance]

**Second one:** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Force Field* > *Vortex*

Change *Noise* to 2 and *Strenght* to 0.1.

[image: Vortex]

**Blend file:**

[image]

**Final toughts:**

I don't know your full setup so some values may vary. You can try change position of force fields and strength/noise values.

**Edit:**

Based on provided blend file I've change all *Force Fields* to *Force* with negative strenght and noise. Also I've zeroed *Velocity* > *Emitter Oject* > *X* and *Random*.

This is how it looks with *Motion Blur.*

[image: Finalfinal]

**Updated blend file:**

[image]

Comment: Check my blend file first and play animation to see if this is what you want. GIF does not show it accuratly.

Comment: ok, I've added my set-up's file, can you give it a look? but to simplify my query, I want the particles to move and behave as fire in the X-direction.

Comment: @Tejas check my edit. I think it's pretty close to fire effect. Tell me if it's ok. You can alway add back one Turbulence force to it.

Comment: @Tejas I've rendered it with Motion Blur to check behavior and it looks pretty neat. Check edit.

Comment: thanks mate, i'll check it now... sorry that i couldn't reply earlier :)

Comment: This is superb, man... thanks for all the help :)